# How can I lock images to a cell in excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Ok, so I am using Microsoft Excel 2010 and have a set up currently where I have 2 views expanded and deflated using the `Group` or `+/-` function. My problem is that the UI has images on the workbook, too. The images are over the cells which are to be "hidden" when the `-` button is pressed and I would like the images to disappear with them. This is not curently happening, instead they are moving to the next visible cell. I have included an example below in case I wasn't clear.

I wish to hide Columns `M:AU` and the images are in various cells, such as `N5` and `O5`. When I collapse (hide) the column range, all of the images move to `AV5`, the next row along that isn't hidden. This means the workbooks are looking messy when collapsed which is the opposite of what I was trying to do. Can anyone advise on a way around this?

Answer (score 4):

Right-click on each image, and:
[image: Excel picture menu][image: Excel picture Size and Properties dialog box]
(Tested in Excel 2007.)

Answer (score -1):

In excel 2010 its in a different place.  Once you click on size and properties and go inside you have to click on properties then choose your object positioning

Comment: This seems to be the exact same way as Scott already pointed out. Look at his picture

Comment: The UI is slightly different in 2010, but the instructions are the same.